# JavaScript table of powers (nested for loop)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table, nested

Got the number column and squared column working however I can't figure out how to do the cubed/fourth/fifth/sixth column.

I know that I need to use at least 2 nested for loops to fill the rows and columns. And I know that x^3 should be x * x * x , and x^4 should be x * x * x * x , etc.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Table of Powers</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

document.writeln("<TABLE BORDER = '1' WIDTH = '100%'>");
document.writeln("<TR><TH WIDTH = '100'><B>x</b></TH>");
document.writeln("<TH><B>x^2</B></TH>");
document.writeln("<TH><B>x^3</B></TH>");
document.writeln("<TH><B>x^4</B></TH>");
document.writeln("<TH><B>x^5</B></TH>");
document.writeln("<TH><B>x^6</B></TH></TR>");

for (var count = 1; count <=10; count++)
{
    document.writeln("<TR><TD>" + count + "</TD><TD>" + square(count));
    function square(x)
    {
        return x*x;
    }
}
document.writeln("</TABLE>");

</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The output should look like this :

```
x       x^2     x^3     x^4     x^5     x^6
1       1       1       1       1       1
2       4       8       16      32      64
3       9       27      81      243     729
4       16      64      256     1,024   4,096
5       25      125     625     3,125   15,625
6       36      216     1,296   7,776   46,656
7       49      343     2,401   16,807  117,649
8       64      512     4,096   32,768  262,144
9       81      729     6,561   59,049  531,441
10      100     1,000   10,000  100,000 1,000,000
```

Comment: Hint: You might want to take a look at the `pow` function of the Math library [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use [Math.pow function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp)

something like this,

```
for (var base = 1;base <=10;base++)
{document.writeln("<TR>");
for (var count = 1; count <=6; count++)
{
    document.writeln( "<TD>"  + Math.pow(base,count)+"</TD>");

}
document.writeln("</TR>");
}
```

Comment: Even if I do, I am still unsure on how to fillout the rows and columns of the table using nested for loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
    document.writeln("<TABLE BORDER = '1' WIDTH = '100%'>");
    document.writeln("<TR><TH WIDTH = '100'><B>x</b></TH>");
    document.writeln("<TH><B>x^2</B></TH>");
    document.writeln("<TH><B>x^3</B></TH>");
    document.writeln("<TH><B>x^4</B></TH>");
    document.writeln("<TH><B>x^5</B></TH>");
    document.writeln("<TH><B>x^6</B></TH></TR>");

    for (var count = 1; count <= 10; count++) {
        document.writeln("<TR><TD>" + count + "</TD><TD>" + square(count) + "</TD>");
        document.writeln("<TD>" + cubed(count)) + "</TD>";
        document.writeln("<TD>" + fourth(count)) + "</TD>";
        document.writeln("<TD>" + five(count)) + "</TD>";
        document.writeln("<TD>" + six(count)) + "</TD>";
        function square(x) {
            return x * x;
        }
        function cubed(x) {
            return x * x *x;
        }
        function fourth(x) {
            return x * x * x * x;
        }
        function five(x) {
            return x * x * x *x * x;
        }
        function six(x) {
            return x * x * x * x * x *x;
        }
    }
    document.writeln("</TABLE>");
</script>
```

You could always replace the power functions with more succinct loops but that should give the output you needed.

Comment: You must not put function declarations in a loop body.